1980s cartoon about a group of kids lost in time?
I was talking with a friend and we were trying to remember a cartoon we watched in the 80s as small children.  There was a group of friends that were trapped in some sort of time warp and at the end of the show it would always seem like they were about to get back but as far as we recall they never did.  We remember a roller coaster type things being a big part of the show, a lot of fantasy/adventure, and bad guys.  What is the show and did they ever make it back?

Dungeons and Dragons (1983-1985) was the name of the cartoon.

The show focused on a group of six friends who are transported into
  the titular realm and followed their adventures as they tried to find
  a way home with the help of their guide 'Dungeon Master'. A final
  un-produced episode would have served as a conclusion as well as a
  re-imagining had the series been picked up for a fourth season.
  However, the show was cancelled before the episode was made. The
  script can be found from various sources online and was performed as
  an audio drama as a special feature for the BCI Eclipse DVD edition of
  the series.


I am going to have to watch a clip or two to figure out if this is it.  The screen shots don't seem familiar but who knows it was a while ago.

Yes that is it.  Thank you.  We remember them playing some episode where they were in a garden maze literally every other week for months.  And we thought we missed the last episode... It was quite the show during that time because they showed it on Sunday mornings.  There were only a couple of cartoons on network TV on Sunday mornings and that was one of the few decent ones - even though it may seem tragically bad now.
